# Is this safe? (a take on deserialisation)

Tags: serialization, lua

I wanted to be sure that the function below is 100% safe wrt code injection attacks. Specifically can anyone find an argument to the function below that allows the caller to retrieve a table with executable Lua code in it, or cause the function to compile\exec anything passed to it via the function argument?

(I took this off-beat approach because things like co-routines and the debug library and similar are restricted in my application. Function callers will know about the argument's 'function' text key constraint; see below)

Attempt #1: (FAIL / unsafe)

```
--[[ string2table(s : string)

    De-serialise the string argument into a Lua table. 

    s should define a string serialised Lua constructor

    However, no value of s can:
        embed any code that can be executed at any stage by the caller
        cause a runtime error during exec of the function

    Pre:
        Requires Lua v5.3
        string2table() is in the global env.
        The caller has no acccess to load or pcall. i.e the caller is in a jail

        s should represent a serialised Lua constructor as a string starting with "{".
        s cannot not be pre-compiled or the function will return an error.
        s must not encode any table key containing the text "function".

    Return Value:

        On success

            table : s de-serialised into a lua table. Bascially pcall(load(s))

        On fail

            nil, errmsg
]]

function string2table(s)
    if type(s) ~= "string" then return nil, "call format: string2table(string)" end
    if string.find(s, "{") ~= 1 then return nil, "string arg must begin with '{'" end -- just a hint, this affords no protection
    s = "return"..string.gsub(s, "function", "fun\\99tion")     -- NB   \99 = "c"
    -- The return & gsub above prevents embedding any code in s.
    -- Specifically re the gsub:
    --      when the text 'function' appears in a lua string it gets converted to 'function' ie no effect.
    --      when the text 'function' appears outside of a lua string it gets converted to 'fun\99tion' causing the pcall to fail.
    -- The cost of the gsub aprroach is that s can't define any table key with the text "function" in it.
    -- However any "function" text embedded in a string will be unaffected.

    local jail = {}
    local f, err = load(s, "string2table:", "t", jail)
    if err then return nil, err end   -- it didnt compile, return the error
    local ok, torErrmsg = pcall(f)

    if not ok then return nil, torErrmsg end -- runtime error occured
    return torErrmsg -- all ok, return the table
end

--[[ Example arguments:

        "{s = \"function\"}"                                            -- rv = true, {s = "function"}
        "{f = (function () while true do end end)()}"                   -- value is a function call; rv = nil, [string "string2table:"]:1: ')' expected near '\'
        "{[(function () while true do end return 123 end)()] = 456}"    -- key is a function call;   rv = nil, [string "string2table:"]:1: ')' expected near '\'
        "{a = t.IdontExist}"                                            -- runtime error; rv = nil, [string "string2table:"]:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 't')

]]
```

Thanks all for the great feedback. Especially Egor.

Attempt #2 based on initial feedback. Attempt #2 now also disables the string library meta methods e.g. s="{('a'):rep(99):find(('.*'):rep(99)..'b')}"

```
--[[ string2table(s : string)

De-serialise the string argument into a Lua table.

s should define a string serialised Lua constructor

However, no value of s can:
    embed any code that can be executed at any stage by the caller
    cause a runtime error during exec of the function

Pre:
    Requires Lua v5.3
    string2table() is in the global env.
    The caller has no acccess to load or pcall. i.e the caller is in a jail
    Assumes the string library is present/visible.

    s should represent a serialised Lua constructor as a string starting with "{".
    s cannot not be pre-compiled or the function will return an error.
    s must not encode any table key containing the text "function".

Warning:
    Inefficient (invokes Lua compiler).
        Recommend JSON & JSON lib for frequent use over this function.

Return Value:

    On success

        table : s de-serialised into a lua table. Bascially pcall(load(s))

    On fail

        nil, errmsg
]]

do

    local s_load         = load
    local string_mt      = getmetatable("")

    function string2table(s)
        if type(s) ~= "string" then return nil, "call format: string2table(string)" end
        if string.find(s, "{") ~= 1 then return nil, "string arg must begin with '{'" end -- just a hint, this affords no protection
        s = "return"..string.gsub(s, "function", "fun\\99tion")     -- NB   \99 = "c"
        -- The return & gsub above prevents embedding most code from being embedded in s.
        -- Specifically re the gsub:
        --      when the text 'function' appears in a lua string it gets converted to 'function' ie no effect.
        --      when the text 'function' appears outside of a lua string it gets converted to 'fun\99tion' causing the pcall to fail.
        -- The cost of the gsub aprroach is that s can't define any table key with the text "function" in it.
        -- However any "function" text embedded in a string will be unaffected.

        -- gsub option:    string.gsub(s, "%f[%w_]function%f[^%w_]", "fun\\99tion")
        -- This variation above should safely allows keys with ..'function'.. in the key text to still load e.g. "{functional = true}"
        -- [ed: I simply havent used this alt. gsub yet because im still learning Lua patterns and %f still confuses me]

        local jail = {}

        local f, err = s_load(s, "string2table:", "t", jail) -- "t" means only text chunks
        if err then return nil, err end   -- it didnt compile, return the error

        -- The string library's metatable represents a gaping hole in the jail. Temporarily close it.
        -- This will ensure strings like this "{('a'):rep(99):find(('.*'):rep(99)..'b')}" are caught as an error.
        string_mt.__index = nil -- disable string lib metatable

        local ok, torErrmsg = pcall(f)

        string_mt.__index = string
        if not ok then return nil, torErrmsg end -- runtime error occured
        return torErrmsg -- all ok, return the table
    end
end

--[[ quick test cases:

    "{s = \"function\"}"                                            -- rv = true, {s = "function"}
    "{f = (function () while true do end end)()}"                   -- value is a function call; rv = nil, [string "luaDoStringLua:simple"]:1: ')' expected near '\'
    "{[(function () while true do end return 123 end)()] = 456}"    -- key is a function call;   rv = nil, [string "luaDoStringLua:simple"]:1: ')' expected near '\'
    "{a = t.IdontExist}"                                            -- runtime error; rv = nil, [string "luaDoStringLua:simple"]:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 't')
    "{('a'):rep(99):find(('.*'):rep(99)..'b')}"                     -- If string if exec'd it will hang the Lua interpreter.
]]
```

Comment: To allow identifiers containing word "function" as a substring: `string.gsub(s, "%f[%w_]function%f[^%w_]", "fun\\99tion")`  Example: `string2table("{functional = true}")`

Comment: Some input strings may hang your Lua VM: `string2table("{('a'):rep(99):find(('.*'):rep(99)..'b')}")`

Comment: Also IIRC malicious bytecode could also cause issues with the interpreter, so you want to make sure you're only loading source code.

Comment: Here's a thought: to make this less risky, why not accept JSON rather than a Lua table string, and use one of the existing JSON parsing libraries? That would solve any problems with having expressions in table keys or values, as only literal values are allowed in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way of breaking it. You can get the `jail` table in Lua 5.2+ by doing this:

```
local jail = string2table("{_ENV}")[1]
```

But it doesn't matter if you add things to the jail table after `string2table` is run, because a new jail table is generated every time. (Just don't reuse the table!)

I don't think I know Lua sandboxing well enough to declare it safe, however. There may be things I have overlooked.

Also, consider replacing `string.find(s, "{") ~= 1` with `string.sub(s, 1, 1) ~= "{"`. That way you don't have to search through the whole string to check whether the first character is an opening brace.